# How to change the file path in the terminal of VS Code to be like the actual (real) path to make me able to run code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

How to change this path in the terminal:

[image: (THE PATH THAT SHOWN IN THE TERMINAL)]

to the actual path below?

[image: (THE REAL PATH)]

This causes that I couldn't run my code.

This problem prevents me to try my first line of code.

Comment: learn how to use the terminal for the OS you use, learn the shell commands needed to change the directory

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when we first open vscode, we need to set the workspace (**File -> Open Folder**).

[image]

When you set up the workspace, terminal will default to setting the workspace as the area for executing files.

Another way is to use [debug mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging). Adding `"program": "${file}"` to your `launch.json` means debugging current file.

If you only want to modify the current path in the terminal, VSCode is just a code editor, and the operations in the terminal are exactly the same as using the shell normally. You can run command `cd D:\programming\0\installing` to achieve it.